# Unable to automate Dynamic Paint baking through Blender's API

Tags: python, scripting, baking, dynamic-paint

I am not new to python, but I am to the Blender API and I am attempting to write a small script to automate the baking process for groups of canvases. I started with a test group called Panels, using the API I find the correct collection, then iterate over the objects to set as active and bake them.

Initially it would start each bake then immediately move to the next one causing crashes so I implemented a check with `os.listdir()`, to see if the output directory had the proper amount of frames, and a cautionary `time.sleep()` since `bpy.ops.dpaint.bake()` doesn't return anything. Now I can get through the first one just fine, but when it comes to the second bake it fails to start, Blender hangs, and the console just spits out '0/xxx', <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> just crashes blender.

The [Dynamic Paint documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.83/bpy.ops.dpaint.html#bpy.ops.dpaint.bake) have only gotten me so far as they are pretty bare and I cant find anyone else with this issue. Using this iteration method I had no problem performing other actions such as translating, scaling, and material changes.

Any ideas on why this code not working would be greatly appreciated!

```
import bpy
import time
import os

collectionName = 'Panels'

for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    
    #check if we have the right collection
    if collection.name == collectionName:
        
        for object in collection.objects:
            
            # test
            print(object)
            
            # set object as active for baking
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object
            
            # shorthand the modifier
            DPaintMod = object.modifiers[0].canvas_settings.canvas_surfaces[0]
            
            # set sim length
            simLen = DPaintMod.frame_end - DPaintMod.frame_start

            # set folder to check            
            absPath = bpy.path.abspath(DPaintMod.image_output_path[:-1])
            
            # test 
            print(absPath)
            
            # makedir if none
            if not os.path.exists(absPath):
                os.mkdir(absPath)
            
            # clean the directory first
            if len(os.listdir(absPath)) > 0:
                for img in os.listdir(absPath):
                    os.remove(absPath+"/"+img)    
            
            # do the bake
            bpy.ops.dpaint.bake()
            
            # maybe helpful?
            time.sleep(1)

            # check for bake completion
            while len(os.listdir(absPath)) < simLen+1:
                print(len(os.listdir(absPath)),"/",simLen+1)
            
            print("finished")
            
            # maybe helpful?
            time.sleep(2)
```